# What's the exclamation mark at the beginning and dollar sign at the end of regex?

Tags: regex, mean.io

I"m using Mean.io and saw an regex in a modRewrite function:

```
app.use(modRewrite([

   '!^/api/.*|\\_getModules|\\.html|\\.js|\\.css|\\.mp4|\\.swf|\\.jp(e?)g|\\.png|\\.gif|\\.svg|\\.ico|\\.eot|\\.ttf|\\.woff|\\.pdf$ / [L]'

]));
```

I understand that they're trying to rewrite the url to be prettier by replacing any urls containing:

```
/api/, _getModules, .html, .js, ..., .pdf
```

However, I have been searching in order to understand the regex but still can't figure it out what is the `!^` at the beginning of the line and `$` at the end of the line. Could someone please extract the regex step by step?

Comment: negation... not of the match

Comment: @AvinashRaj I though it should be 
`!(^(/api/.*|\\_getModules|\\.html|\\.js|\\.css|\\.mp4|\\.swf|\\.jp(e?)g|\\.png|\\.gif|\\.svg|\\.ico|\\.eot|\\.ttf|\\.woff|\\.pdf)$)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [*Apache mod_rewrite Introduction*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html):

> In mod_rewrite the `!` character can be used before a regular expression to negate it. This is, a string will be considered to have matched only if it does not match the rest of the expression.

The `^` and `$` are [regex anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) that assert the position at the start and end of string respectively.

To understand the rest, you can go through the [What does the regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) post.

The regex itself is:

- `^` - Assert the start of string position and...
- `/api/.*` - Match literally `/api/` and 0 or more characters other then newline
- `|` - Or...
- `\\_getModules` - Match `_getModules`
- `|` - Or
- `\\.html` - Match `.html`
- `|\\.js|\\.css|\\.mp4|\\.swf|\\.jp(e?)g|\\.png|\\.gif|\\.svg|\\.ico|\\.eot|\\.ttf|\\.woff|` - Or these extensions (note it will match `jpg` and `jpeg` as `?` means *match 0 or 1 occurrence of preceding pattern*)
- `\\.pdf$` - Match `.pdf` right at the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: Well, the regex is really very simple: just a couple of alternatives (with `|` alternation operator) and *any-character-but-newline* matching with `.*` . The dot is escaped to match a literal dot (as `.` matches any character but a newline).

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I want to escape the dot, it should be `\.html`, shouldn't it? In this case, `\\.html`, this escapes the backslash instead of dot.

Comment: Mean.io is JavaScript-based. In JavaScript, you have to use ``\\`` to specify a literal ``\`` that is necessary when defining regex escape sequences (like `\s` matching whitespace, or `\w` matching alphanumeric and underscore symbols). In case the regex is defined with a string literal (i.e. `/\s\.jpg/`) there is no need to double the ``\`` symbol.

Comment: I understand what you described in the comment, however, in my example, I still didn't get it. Could you please extract the regex shown in my example piece my piece if you have time? BTW, I accepted your answer as well.

Comment: Yes, I will. Just note that if the escape sequence is not valid, ``\`` is treated as a literal. I will do the regex break down after bringing my son home.

Comment: Really great explanation! Thanks so much again. It might be a stupid question but why we use double back slashes `\\_getModules` instead of just `\_getModules`? IMHO, one back slash will also give us `_getModules` since it would escape the underscore character as well.

Comment: I think you are right, and this is in line with what I wrote before: if the escape sequence is unknown, the ``\`` is treated as a literal.

Comment: I got it. Thanks @stribizhev.